# SELECT statement with multiple conditions on TAGs

Tags: influxdb

For considerably long period of time I’ve been struggling the following problem. This is an example of data stored in the DB:

```
> show series
flights,cycleId=1535,cycleIdx=0,engineId=2,flightId=1696,flightIdx=0,type=fil
flights,cycleId=1535,cycleIdx=0,engineId=2,flightId=1696,flightIdx=0,type=std
flights,cycleId=1535,cycleIdx=0,engineId=2,flightId=1696,flightIdx=0,type=raw
...
```

and my intention is to select a specific one by using a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM flights WHERE type='fil' AND engineId= '2' AND flightId = '1696' AND flightIdx = '0' AND cycleId = '1535' AND cycleIdx = '0'
```

Such query, however, yields always zero results. Zilch.

Selecting the first (and only) tag works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM flights WHERE cycleId = '1535'
```

but using this condition on any other tag, like for example

```
SELECT * FROM flights WHERE type='fil'
```

does never return a single row. Querying only the first tag and nothing else works.

Could you please give me a hint what am I doing wrong? From all I have found people are always selecting just by a single tag but never more. What is the part that I cannot see?

Many thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have discovered the reason: two keys from the tags made by mistake their way into the fields. I spotted the trouble when listing the tag and fields keys as

```
show tag keys
show field keys
```

Deleting all records does not remove the keys from these lists and the problem persists. One need to drop the entire database to restore the order of things.